# Character compare not working to end loop

Tags: c

So I'm stuck here, and dunno why doesn't this work.

```
do{
    char cf;
    scanf(" %c",&cf);
}while(cf!='s' || cf!='S');
```

It doesn't end the loop when I press S or s.

Comment: Logically, if `cf='s'` then it is *not* `S`, so your end condition returns `true`. It also does for the reverse case! Use `&&` ('AND') instead.

Comment: BTW: Nice to see the space in `" %c"` but friends don't let friends code with `scanf()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this should not even compile since `cf` is out of scope where the condition is being checked.

Second. This'll be always true since `cf` will always be "not s or not S".

THis is how you can fix it:

```
  char cf; 
  do{ 
    scanf(" %c",&cf);
  }while(cf!='s' && cf!='S');
```

Note: You could also write the condition like this, which is the logical equivalent of the above:

```
 while(!(cf=='s'||cf=='S'))
```

Comment: "It doesn't compile", that is also a pretty strong clue for the OP :)

Comment: OMG, my brain exploded, 2 years programming and now I get this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition is wrong.
It should be:

> while(cf!='s' && cf!='S');